# Trying to save specific file with his name folder

Tags: powershell, scripting

firstly excuse my self because i'm a newbie and it's realy hard for me to do simple script.

I trying to save some specific files with there directory parent

Exemple : Here i want to save name of "Folder2" "Folder4" and files2, 3, 6.

```
Folder1\Folder2\
              |===> File1
              |===> File2
              |===> File3
Folder3\Folder4\
              |===> File4
              |===> File5
              |===> File6
```

For create this tree in my save :

```
Save\Folder2\
              |===> File2
              |===> File3
Save\Folder4\
              |===> File6
```

I trying with this :

```
$Src = "C:\Folder3\"
$Dst = "C:\Save\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Recurse -Name "File2.txt" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_); New-Item -Path $Dst -Name $_}
```

I pretty sure it's really easy but i really don't understand how powershell work.

Thanks

Comment: How do you decide which files to copy and which to leave? In general you can use robocopy to copy files. this way you don't need a script at all.

Comment: Step back and do this effort one step at a time, to make sure you are getting the results you'd expect before moving to the next step. IT appears that you are doing this in the console host, but you can do this in the ISE or VSCode to make your life a bit easier, meaning, you get more dynamic help as you type things, as well and so you can debug along the way.  Not knowing how PowerShell works, is really your first issue of this confusion. Look for PowerShell videos on Youtube to get you up to speed and help avoid the confusion you are currently having.

Comment: Lastly, don't get in the habit of putting everything on one line, as that does not make your code a one-liner. THose semi-colons specifically indicate that each of those are separate code blocks that have no relation to the other. It also makes the code hard to read, debug adn maintain. In the interactive shell (consolehost), I get this, but you can do multi-line code even there, though it's a bit more cumbersome, than in a real ediror, i.e, the ISE or VSCode or other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering so that only containers (directories) are returned You will never have a file object to copy.

If we know more about what you're trying to do we could probably polish this up nicely.  So, this is just a start, but try something like:

```
$SrcRoot = "C:\temp\01-24-20"
$DstRoot = "C:\temp\Save\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcRoot -Recurse -Directory | 
ForEach-Object{
    $Root   = $_ # Makes it easier to reference the object in the outer ForEach loop.
    $DstSub = New-Item -Path $DstRoot -Name $Root.Name -ItemType Directory

    # > From your initial code it doesn't look like you need recursion here.
    # > Also you may want to add the -Filter parameter to add a wildcard pattern
    Get-ChildItem $Root.FullName -File | 
    ForEach-Object{
        # > Add an If block below to make the copy conditional.
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination $DstSub
    }
}
```

Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

By why are you setting these this way, when your diagram shows you are also using another folder...

```
Folder1\Folder2\
```

... that you are doing nothing within your code but you want files from it.

```
<#
$Src = "C:\Folder3\"
$Dst = "C:\Save\"
#>
```

So, then this. Unless that is a typo.

```
$src1 = 'Folder1\Folder2\'
$Src3 = 'Folder3\Folder4\'
$Dst = 'C:\Save\'
```

You are only asking for a single file here

```
# Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Recurse -Name "File2.txt" |

$src1,$src3 | 
ForEach ($File -in (Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem.FullName) |
```

This also means, you have no idea where this file is in the tree, so, using the -Recurse to scan all of them. Don't scan if you don't have to. Also, why are you looking for a folder here, when you are only asking for a single file or file set?

```
Where-Object {
$_.PSIsContainer} |
```

You are doing a bunch of raw library stuff when there native cmdlets/properties for this sort of thing

```
ForEach-Object {
# [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_)
$PSItem.DirectoryName
```

';' This is a terminator for string unrelated code on the same line. So, drop that and make this its own line. [See why special characters need to be understood here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7) and [punctuation statement separators here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/PSPunctuationWallChart_1_0_4.pdf).

You are also saying you want to save a file to some destination and that does not require the use of New-Item. New-Item is to create a new empty file, but your diagram appears to state you want to move a file or copy a file from the sources

***Folder1\Folder2***

```
          |===> File1
          |===> File2
          |===> File3
```

... to

***Save\Folder2***

```
          |===> File2
          |===> File3
```

... and from

***Folder3\Folder4***

```
          |===> File4
          |===> File5
          |===> File6
```

... to

***Save\Folder4***
              |===> File6

```
If ($Filename -eq 'File2|File3')
{Copy-Item -Path "$Dst\$($Filename.DirectoryName)" -Force}
}
```

Your code appears to be something you copied and pasted from some legacy PowerShell level site and tweaked for what your use case. Nothing wrong with using someone else's code, but not if you do not understand it or are not skilled at using the language of the code use case. Don't cause yourself undue issues.

Again, get some training first. It's virtually all free on Youtube, free online [books](https://martin77s.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/free-powershell-ebooks/), [etc](https://powershell.org/free-resources/). This will help get your mind and skills set to limit confusion, error, bad code/practices/habits, etc.

So, as you can see there is a good deal out of place in your code vs what you are after. Mostly due to what you say as not really knowing how PowerShell works.

So, along with the other suggested answer(s), try something like the below. Yet,  because you've not spent any time studying up on PowerShell, this may not make sense even if it works for you. So, again, jump on Youtube to get some ramp-up first before trying anyone's code.

Just search for:

- ['Beginning PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Beginning%20PowerShell%27)
- ['Intermediate PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Intermediate%20PowerShell%27)
- ['Advanced PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Advanced%20PowerShell%27)
- ['PowerShell file and folder management'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell%20file%20and%20folder%20management%27)
- ['PowerShell copying files'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell%20copying%20files%27)
- ['PowerShell moving files'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell%20moving%20files%27)
- ['PowerShell Loop'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell%20Loop%27)
- ['Learn PowerShell in a Month of Lunches'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Learn%20PowerShell%20in%20a%20Month%20of%20Lunches%27)

Use the built-in help files and the examples there, practice with those and read the help files again:

```
# See all help topics
Select-Object -Property Name, Synopsis |
Out-GridView -Title 'Select Topic' -OutputMode Multiple |
ForEach-Object { Get-Help -Name $_.Name -ShowWindow }

explorer "$pshome\$($Host.CurrentCulture.Name)"

# get function / cmdlet details
Get-Command -Name Copy-Item -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Copy-Item).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Full
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Online
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Examples


Get-Command -Name Move-Item -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Move-Item).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Move-Item -Full
Get-help -Name Move-Item -Online
Get-help -Name Move-Item -Examples
```

So, in PowerShell, there are always a number of ways to do X or Y thing, some solutions more elegant than others, but here is an example of what I feel you are after. Again, this is a very rough thing and can be tweaked to make it better, or go a different way, based on the use case.

```
# Clear the screen
Clear-Host

# Set source and destination resources
$src1 = 'D:\Temp\ParentFolder'
$src3 = 'D:\Test\Reference'
$Dst = 'D:\Save'

# Pipe in the source items
$src1,$src3 | 
<#
Loop through the source items
#>
ForEach{
    <#
    Read the source items to locate specific files
    #>
    Get-ChildItem -Path $PSItem -Include Test_Audio.csv,hello.bat,ParentWELCOM98.WAV -Recurse | 
    ForEach {
        <#
        Target only specif cfile names
        #>
        If($PSitem -match 'Test_Audio.csv|hello.bat')
        {
            <#
            If this is a match then copy to the destination root by adding the directory of the filename
            Using teh -WhatIf to validate the action before deciding to remove the -WhatIf for actual taks completion.
            #>
            Copy-Item -Path $PSitem.FullName -Destination $Dst\$($PSitem.Directory.BaseName) -WhatIf
        }
        Else 
        {
            <#
            If this is a match then copy to the destination root by adding the directory of the filename
            Using teh -WhatIf to validate the action before deciding to remove teh -WhatIf for actual taks completion.
            #>
            Copy-Item -Path $PSitem.FullName -Destination $Dst\$($PSitem.Directory.BaseName) -WhatIf
        }
    }
}

# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\ParentWELCOM98.WAV Destination: D:\Save\ParentFolder".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Temp\ParentFolder\Test_Audio.csv Destination: D:\Save\ParentFolder".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\Test\Reference\hello.bat Destination: D:\Save\Reference".
#>
```

When you'd remove the [-Whatif](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-whatif/) and use -Force, things will complete and items will be created.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering me with a lot of information. It's pretty hard for me to learn powershell with english tutorial, but dont worry i will try and we have some french tutorial i do my best.

i looking for a folder because i trying to keep the name of the folder and recreate a folder with the same name. also  i miss to say the folder parent have a random name like :

841654186463\file1

I will try to found a way with your help.

Comment: No worries. I hope it gets you to where you need to be, but you'll note from my code sample, I am dynamically pulling the folder name on the copy directly from the file name being searched for. So, that should address your random foldername thing.